# phonegap adobe ios iPad deviceReady not fired until notifications shown

Tags: ios, cordova, adobe

The deviceReady event is not fired when starting the app.

Dragging the notifications list down from the top of the screen and releasing then causes the deviceReady to fire.

Similarly, trying to display a page in the inAppBrowser doesn't display until the notifications are dragged down and released.

Key elements in the config.xml are:-

```
  <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1.0.0" source="npm" />
  <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" version="1.0.1" />
  <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm" version="1.0.1" />
  <preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
  <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
  <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="true" />
```

Html:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" ....  />
</head>
<body >
<div id="idSplash" class="textCenter" >
    <div id="idSplashHeader">
        <div class="headerImg"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div id="idSplashMessage">Starting up ...</div>
    </div>
    <div id="idSplashBody"></div>
    <div id="idSplashFooter"><a id="idTestLink" href="javascript:null" target="_blank">Click here for google</a></div>
</div>

<!-- ************************************************************************** -->
<script src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js" type="text/JavaScript" ></script>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function onReady() {
            $("#idSplashMessage").text("deviceReady");
            alert("deviceReady");
        }
        document.addEventListener("deviceReady", onReady, false);
        $("#idTestLink").click(function () {
            var win = window.open(encodeURI("http://www.google.co.uk"), '_blank', 'location=yes');
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
<script src="cordova.js" type="text/JavaScript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you still having issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of the problems was the inclusion of a content security policy in the html.

Although I believe the CSP was entirely valid, and did not cause any issues with Android, I removed it which allowed the IOS version to work.

The CSP was added in the first place due to an error log from the whitelist plug in suggesting it was required.

Comment: Sorry, did not get your response. I've been forgetting to tell people. **iOS9 is [not official support](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/current-tripping-points.md)**

Answer (score 0):

@Grebe,
this is a common misunderstanding with developers new to Cordova/Phonegap.

From: [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)

**4. In the code, did not listen for the 'deviceready' event.**

> (...) the [section of documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready) we need.
>
> This is a very important event that every Cordova application should use.
>
> Cordova consists of two code bases: native and JavaScript. While the native code is loading, a custom loading image is displayed. However, JavaScript is only loaded once the DOM loads. This means your web application could, potentially, call a Cordova JavaScript function before it is loaded.
>
> The Cordova deviceready event fires once Cordova has fully loaded. After the device has fired, you can safely make calls to Cordova function.

This means you must do this before you call any other libraries.

This also means you need to load `cordova.js` before *jquery*.

#### EXAMPLE

```
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}
// _OR_ JUST
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Cordova is loaded and it is now safe to make calls Cordova methods
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Call the usual stuff.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou. 

The re-positioning of cordova.js enabled the deviceReady event on android. 

However on IOS it seems not to fire until some other activity occurs - such as pulling down the notifications OR the device timing out.

Comment: If your code is available for viewing on a public website, like github or pastebin, I can have a look at it.